# MySQL - 3 different tables with the same column join in 1 column

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

So I'm trying to join 3 tables into 1 column when I query them.

The three tables are

`investigators.name`, `ancientones.name`,`monsters.name`.

The query I used to call back all the names is

`SELECT investigators.name ,ancientones.name ,monsters.name 
FROM investigators, ancientones, monsters
WHERE ((investigators.name LIKE'a%') OR (ancientones.name LIKE'a%')OR (monsters.name LIKE'a%'))`

But what this returns is 3 table rows with the "name" with the values from table 1, 2 and 3. 
I want all the values in a single column, but I don't have that much SQL experience..

Comment: Weird tags, by the way. Even if the goal is to use your query for ajax autocomplete, your question has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use UNION (or UNION ALL to keep duplicates)

```
SELECT name
FROM investigators
WHERE name like 'a%'
UNION
SELECT name 
FROM anientones
WHERE name like 'a%'
UNION
SELECT name
FROM monsters
WHERE name like 'a%'
```

Answer (score 0):

try using '+' between column names

```
SELECT investigators.name + ' ' + ancientones.name + ' ' + monsters.name FROM investigators, ancientones, monsters WHERE ((investigators.name LIKE'a%') OR (ancientones.name LIKE'a%')OR (monsters.name LIKE'a%'))
```